# Number of non-zero code words in $C$ with minimal hamming distance from $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces, coding-theory

> Let $C$ be the linear code with letters in $\mathbb{F}_7$ with parity check matrix $H$ whose columns are vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1\\
> \alpha\\
> \alpha^{2}
> \end{bmatrix}$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_7$. Find the number of words in $C$ that are different from the $0$ word and have minimal distance from $0$ (meaning, all $x\in C$ s.t $\|x\|=d(C)$, with $d(C)$ the minimal hamming distance of $C$).

My attempt:
First I was asked to find the parameters of $C$. I found that the parameters are $[7,4,4]_7$, and proved that the code is optimal ($A_7(7,4)=7^4$).

Now I defined $$A=\{x\in\mathbb{F}_7^7:\|x\|=4\}$$ By combinatorical calculations, $|A|=\binom{7}{4}6^{4}$ - this is because I have to choose $4$ entries to make non-zero, and then decide what number to put in each place between $1-6$. I'm looking for the size of $A\cap C$. I tried using the fact that $x\in A\cap C\iff x\in A$ and $xH^t=0$, but I didn't get anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First note that any three columns of the parity check matrix $H$ are linearly independent (since any three columns form a Vandermonde matrix).  This means that to form a codeword, we may choose any $4$ entries freely, and the remaining three entries can be filled in one and only one way.

To count minimal length nonzero codewords (that is codewords of length $4$), we choose three of the seven entries to be $0$; and then we choose a nonzero value from $\mathbb{F}_7$ to be the leftmost remaining entry (i.e., not one of the $0$ entries). We then determine the unique values of the remaining three entries so as to obtain a codeword. The codeword with these entries is unique. Also this codeword must have weight exactly $4$ since it has a weight between $1$ and $4$, but there are no codewords of length $1, 2$, or $3$.

All this can be done in ${7\choose 3}\cdot 6=210$ ways. So this code has $210$ codewords of weight $4$.